# How do I get screen resolution? I don't want screen size

Tags: java, swing

There have been a lot of questions and answers regarding getting screen resolution here. But virtually all of the answers to getting resolution respond with how to get the screen size. These are not the same things. Size is number of pixels, while resolution is (typically) pixels/inch. I need resolution. How do I get that for the window or frame or dialog on the current device of a multi-device environment? Using Java.

Comment: No, resolution != PPI.

Comment: `getScreenResolution`  gives you the DPI, `getScreenSize` gives you a `Dimension` object with the `height` and `width` of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
int ppi = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
System.out.println( ppi );
```

Comment: Yes, the toolkit provides the screen resolution, but apparently only for the "default" configuration. I need to get the screen resolution for the device the window is currently being displayed upon. I can get the GraphicConfiguration for the window. But that will not provide me the screen resolution. Nor will it provide me a way, even indirectly, to get the toolkit of the current device. the getToolkit call on a Component still only returns the toolkit for the "default" or "initial" device. Does anything else provide the resolution?

Comment: API for the `getToolKit()` method states: *...the frame that contains a component controls which toolkit is used by that component. Therefore if the component is moved from one frame to another, the toolkit it uses may change.* - I don't know if the Toolkit would change if you drag a frame to another device. I don't know how a toolkit is assigned to a frame but would guess it is assigned when the frame is realized( i.e. packed or made visible). I don't know how to position a frame on the second device before it is realized, since I've never used multiple devices. I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the response camickr. I tried getting a new toolkit on the frame that had been moved to the second device, after moving the window of course. I got the same toolkit it had to begin with. So I guess the Java developers just never consider this situation. Apparently no provision is made for it.